# Unity blurry and pixelated sprites in editor (no pixel art)

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, game-development

I am currently making a mobile match-3 like game in unity. I have made all the graphics for the gems(the objects with which you make the matches) in Inkscape at 256x256 and exported them(PNG Files) with 90 dpi(also tried with 360 but nothing changed). My problem is that when I run the game in the editor the graphics seem to be "pixelated" and blurry. In my sprite settings I've set Pixels per Unit to 256, checked Generate Mip Maps, I am using Bilinear Filter Mode and the aniso level is 0. I have also set the max size to 256 and compression to high quality(My Main Camera's size is 10 but I tried to change that and nothing changed as far as the quality of the sprites). What can I do to "perfectly" display my sprites? Do I have to export them in some other way from Inkscape or do I have to change some Unity's settings?
Thank you.

NOTE: My sprites are not "pixel art"!
Edit(Added photos of the purple gem as file and how it is shown in editor):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, mipmaps and bilinear filtering--by definition--blur images. But it would help if you included an image of what you're seeing vs. what you expect.

Comment: @Draco18s i have already tried disabling mipmaps and bilinear filtering but all it does is to make the sprites have sharp ends like pixel art.

Comment: And the example images I asked for?

Comment: @Draco18s I've just added the images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Because scaling

You're display resolution on the images isn't a 256x256 region where those images are displayed, which means that they ***must*** be scaled *in some manner* in order to display in the desired region. *Camera rendering is notoriously bad at scaling.* As your images aren't Vector (and Unity doesn't support vector graphic formats anyway), scaling will always result in a loss of detail. Detail like hard edges.

Your options are:

- smaller images where you have complete control over how the image is scaled down
- bilinear filtering (which is fundamentally blurry)
- mipmaps (which are automatically scaled down versions of your image in powers of two)

If the later two aren't giving satisfactory results, your only option is the first.

Comment: Is it possible to set the number of pixels per unit to 256? If yes, wouldn't it be better than the first option? (The later two options do not make noticeable changes for me)

Comment: Pixels per unit tells Unity what *scale* your sprites exist at: how many pixels fit inside *one game unit.* If your camera shows an area of 10 game units, that's 2560 texture-pixels, but if your screen is only 1024 screen-pixels wide, then 2.5 sprite-pixels need to be crammed into 1 screen-pixel: i.e. scaled down. Largely speaking, the "pixels per unit" value is useless: if you say to use 128 pixels-per-unit instead, your camera needs to encompass 20 game units to see everything, and you still end up with 2560 texture-pixels per 1024 screen-pixels.

Comment: Thank you sir for clarifying this! I made my images smaller, lowered my main camera's size and there is a huge change!

Comment: I am getting the same blurry effects in my image. what do you mean by lowered my main camera size.?

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan The camera size is irrelevant to the problem at hand. It was a thing that N. Spyropoulos had tried and my answer and comment are an explanation of why that has no effect.

Comment: So what is the solution i tried everything here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59099186/image-is-blurry-or-pixlated-in-unity-ui?noredirect=1#comment104447154_59099186

Comment: \*Scrolls up to answer, copies the first bullet, scrolls back down.\* *`Use smaller images where you have complete control over how the image is scaled down`*