# Image is blurry or pixlated in unity UI

Tags: image, unity-game-engine

I have an image which 211x211 here its settings:

[image]

It looks blurry/pixlate in my unity UI. my unity image width height is set 40x40. What i am doing wrong? Even i have tried image 2048x2048 but still getting same blurry effects. The image is not clear.

Here is my game view:

[image]

Comment: Looks like image is already blur before importing to unity. Open it in some Graphic editing software to ensure the quality first.

Comment: Try changing Canvas Scaler's Reference resolution to some big amount (ex. 2500x 1900), if it won't solve your problem then try to play with Reference pixels change it from 100 to 4 or 5 per unit. I think a Reference resolution will work for you.

Comment: @KartikShah nothing works for me

Comment: Try changing Sprite's Pixel Per units

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity blurry and pixelated sprites in editor (no pixel art)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58939661/unity-blurry-and-pixelated-sprites-in-editor-no-pixel-art)

Answer (score 0):

Use Set as **"Native Size in Image"** Component...This will set the size of your Image exactly as it was designed...

Comment: Native size won't help if the native size is too large for what the asker wants to display.

Comment: You have two options here... Ask your designer to redesign the ui.... Or rescale ui using Unity... Please share ScreenShots for more reference...

Comment: They've already rescaled in Unity. That's why it looks bad. Please see the dupe target.